# Twitter share using android error

Tags: android, http, twitter, share

I am using a share button inside my application which use twitter as bellow :

```
 public class TwitterApp {
        private Twitter mTwitter;
        private TwitterSession mSession;
        private AccessToken mAccessToken;
        private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer mHttpOauthConsumer;
        private OAuthProvider mHttpOauthprovider;
        private String mConsumerKey;
        private String mSecretKey;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;
        private TwDialogListener mListener;
        private Context context;

        public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "http://www.rommanapps.com";
        private static final String TAG = "TwitterApp";

        public TwitterApp(Context context, String consumerKey, String secretKey) {
            this.context    = context;

            mTwitter        = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            mSession        = new TwitterSession(context);
            mProgressDlg    = new ProgressDialog(context);

            mProgressDlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            mConsumerKey    = consumerKey;
            mSecretKey      = secretKey;
                mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, secretKey);

            mHttpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);
            mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                                         "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                                         "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

            mAccessToken    = mSession.getAccessToken();

            configureToken();
        }

        public void setListener(TwDialogListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private void configureToken() {
            if (mAccessToken != null) {
                mTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);


                    mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(mAccessToken);

            }
        }

        public boolean hasAccessToken() {
            return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
        }

        public void resetAccessToken() {
            if (mAccessToken != null) {
                mSession.resetAccessToken();

                mAccessToken = null;
            }
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return mSession.getUsername();
        }

        public void updateStatus(String status) throws Exception {
            try {
                mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public void authorize() {
            mProgressDlg.setMessage("Initializing ...");
            mProgressDlg.show();

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String authUrl = "";
                    int what = 1;

                    try {
                        authUrl = mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(mHttpOauthConsumer, CALLBACK_URL);    

                        what = 0;

                        Log.d(TAG, "Request token url " + authUrl);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get request token");

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0, authUrl));
                }
            }.start();
        }

        public void processToken(String callbackUrl)  {
            mProgressDlg.setMessage("Finalizing ...");
            mProgressDlg.show();

            final String verifier = getVerifier(callbackUrl);

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int what = 1;

                    try {
                        mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer, verifier);

                        mAccessToken = new AccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer.getToken(), mHttpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());

                        configureToken();

                        User user = mTwitter.verifyCredentials();

                        mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, user.getName());

                        what = 0;
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting access token");

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
                }
            }.start();
        }

        private String getVerifier(String callbackUrl) {
            String verifier  = "";

            try {
                callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace("twitterapp", "http");

                URL url         = new URL(callbackUrl);
                String query    = url.getQuery();

                String array[]  = query.split("&");

                for (String parameter : array) {
                     String v[] = parameter.split("=");

                     if (URLDecoder.decode(v[0]).equals(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER)) {
                         verifier = URLDecoder.decode(v[1]);
                         break;
                     }
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return verifier;
        }

        private void showLoginDialog(String url) {
            final TwDialogListener listener = new TwDialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String value) {
                    processToken(value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String value) {
                    mListener.onError("Failed opening authorization page");
                }
            };

            new TwitterDialog(context, url, listener).show();
        }

        private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                mProgressDlg.dismiss();

                if (msg.what == 1) {
                    if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                        mListener.onError("Error getting request token");
                    else
                        mListener.onError("Error getting access token");
                } else {
                    if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                        showLoginDialog((String) msg.obj);
                    else
                        mListener.onComplete("");
                }
            }
        };

        public interface TwDialogListener {
            public void onComplete(String value);       

            public void onError(String value);
        }
    }
```

I am having an error with this statement

1. mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                                                            "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                                                            "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

which says **The constructor DefaultOAuthProvider(String, String, String) is undefined**

1. mAccessToken    = mSession.getAccessToken();

which says **Type mismatch: cannot convert from twitter4j.auth.AccessToken to twitter4j.http.AccessToken**

And I don't know where is the problem ! please help

Comment: Those are compile time errors, you need to fix your app. Maybe you are using a sample that is not compatible with the current API of the library you are using (twitter4j).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the library available at below link. It helps me to integrate twitter easily in my android application along with facebook and linkedin.

The project also says they are looking to add more social clients soon.

http://socialauth.in/